# Android Threading - Executing One thread before all others are executed

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I'm new to Android programming and I have a threading issue.

I'm basically populating a GridView with images from 50 or so URLs, but those URLs will not be known until I retrieve a JSON object from an already known URL. I know that I have to fire off a bunch of threads for each URL download (using the AsyncTask class).

How can I effectively queue these threads so that the JSON thread is executed and finished first, so I can use data retrieved from that thread when I fire off those 50 image threads immediately after?

Answer (score 2):

Do not start 50 threads. Use a single thread. While this should be separate from the UI thread for responsiveness, there is no need to spawn multiple threads, and certainly not one thread per URL.ce

Simply make your JSON network call, then parse the response, then (in the same thread) loop through the URLs requesting each one, and decoding the result into a Bitmap. You'd them add them within some model object to the Adapter for your GridView, which would automatically trigger the GridView to update on the UI thread.

There are better practices here, such as lazy loading, caching, and displaying a placeholder image while images are loading, but the exact implementation becomes too complex to describe here. Search for WeakReferenceMap and LruCache to find examples of the best practices for dynamic image loading into an AdapterView.

Comment: So, that's 50 sequential DNS lookups and 50 sequential HTTP GET reqeusts.  Why do you say that a single thread is a good approach, especially given the latency of wireless links?

Comment: Because if you start 50 requests in parallel your user will quit the app before any of them finish loading.

Comment: I'm basically doing something along the lines of http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

It doesn't do 50 at once, just whatever is currently in the gridview. It works fine. That's not the problem

A new thread is created whenever a grid element in the gridview tries to populate itself

Comment: @MarkRenouf - why?  Multiple, concurrent DNS lookups etc. work OK on desktop apps.  What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could just run the first fetch and when this is done, fire the 50 threads from this main thread. As Android 3.0 and later will kill your app when you do network communication from the UI thread, an `AsyncTask` could be a way for to fetch the JSON. When this returns it could fire the other threads.

One thing you should still consider is that Android is, as powerful as it is, still a device with limited capabilities. 50 Threads may use more resources that the target handset has and thus your app may be killed by the system (e.g. because of OOME). So wile on a desktop 50 threads don't sound much, they are much on a phone.

Also IIrc, there is a limit in the http spec, that one may only have 4 (?) simultaneous connections to one remote server. So consider queuing up the image loading requests and fetching them one after the other.

Comment: I'm using the    AsyncTask to retrieve images (using dummy URLs). That's working fine. But I'm not sure how to organize those threads to basically not fire off until another AsyncTask thread retrieves that JSON object

Comment: It's not just the image loads, it's the DNS requests first.  Still, four threads and a producer-consumer queue is sure to be faster than one thread and a limit of 4 seems a reasonable start in an mobile device with limited resources.  I would probably make it configurable so I could easily try different thread pool depths.